# line breaking in mbox environment

Tags: line-breaking, text

I'm writing a combinatorics resume for me so I need to write things like some number is equal to the number of objects satisfying some condition. In the way of this I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\row}{\operatorname{row}}
\newcommand{\col}{\operatorname{col}}

\begin{document}
    \[M_{\lambda \alpha}=\#\mbox{matrices such that \\ \row(A)=\lambda, \col(A)=\alpha}\]
\end{document}
```

`but`\` is not giving the break line I need. Probably I'm not using the right environment?

Basically what I want is an equality of two things but in the right-hand side I need two lines (or more...)

p.s: obviously I defined \row and \col in the preamble...

Comment: (i) in your example `mbox` is wrongly used (ii) in LaTeX is used `\[` and `\]` for open and close equation environment instead of TeX `$$`, (iii) for multi line equations you need to use one of  math environments defined in the `amsmath` package (`align`, `gather`, etc), on the end, please extend your code fragment to complete self contained document, which we can compile as it is.

Comment: @Zarko thanks fr (i) and (ii). I think I've wrote what you are asking me for.

Comment: Use a `\parbox{width}{text}` instead, it allows linebreaks

Comment: Hi @daleif thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, if the following is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % is default for recent article
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\row}{\operatorname{row}}
\newcommand{\col}{\operatorname{col}}
% other packages in your preamble are not relevant for your example

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
M_{\lambda \alpha} & = \text{\# matrices such that} \\
                   &\qquad   \row(A)=\lambda, \col(A)=\alpha
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\row}{\operatorname{row}}
\newcommand{\col}{\operatorname{col}}

\begin{document}
\[
M_{\lambda \alpha} = 
    \begin{aligned}
    & \text{\# matrices such that} \\
    & \row(A)=\lambda, \col(A)=\alpha
    \end{aligned}
\]
or
\[
M_{\lambda \alpha} = \#\
    \begin{aligned}
    & \text{matrices such that} \\
    & \row(A)=\lambda, \col(A)=\alpha
    \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi zarko! It is almost what I'm looking for. I need the line break but! I would like the `=`arrayed in the middle line between "matrices such that" and "row(A) = ..., col(A)= ... ". I hope my explanation is clear ^^U

Comment: @UnPerrito, see addendum to answer.

Comment: you got it! thank you very much!